# Which version of firefox is compatible with Selenium 3.3.1 without use of gecodriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to run scripts on Firefox having selenium webdriver version installed as 3.3.1 but w/o any use of geco driver.
kindly help as I am working on client machine

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot work with Selenium 3.3.1 without using geckodriver.

Selenium 2.53 was the last version which worked without gecko driver with Mozila Firefox (till version 47.x)

To work with Selenium 3.3.1 you need to mandatory download gecko driver v0.15.0 from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and save it. Upgrade your Mozila Firefox to 53.x

Note that: For gecko driver v0.15.0 you must upgrade to Selenium 3.3 since this release aligns HTTP responses with the WebDriver standard.

Next you need to provide the absolute path of the gecko driver in your code. Your code will look like:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",  "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys("your_username");
```

Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: @AshishJain Have you tried working with the latest source of project to fulfill your requirements ? You might need to keep Firefox driver implementation as per your needs. As far as using release jars are concerned it is not possible using Selenium 3 w/o gecko.